# Suppose f is continuously differentiable at least twice with the condition that f is an even function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If f'(a) does not equal f'(b) does not equal 0, prove that

(f'(a)+f'(b))/2 = (f(a)-f(b))/(a-b)

This is asking to prove that the average derivative between two non critical points is equal to their secant slope.

Unless someone can come up with an example where it does not work I will redefine my question. I am thinking this has never been proven. Any thoughts?

Comment: I suppose you mean that $f'(a)\neq 0 \neq f'(b)$? Because swapping $a$ and $b$ gives this conclusion. And do you really mean that $f'(a)\neq f'(b)$?

Comment: I mean this theorem doesn't work if we take the average between two derivatives where they are 0.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not true in general.**

Take the even function defined for $x \ge 0$ by $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: I would guess you could use (almost) any function.

Comment: Agree.  $f(x)=x^2$ is however a wrong choice as a counterexample.

Comment: This function is not continuously differentiable at x=0